# Port Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. in chrome extension, how to fix?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Port I'm creating in popup js.
Error is `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

Error line: `popup.html:0`

**My manifest v3**

```
{
    "name": "Extension title",
    "description": "Extension title",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": ["browsingData", "tabs", "activeTab", "scripting"],
    "host_permissions": ["*://*.example.io/*"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "matches": ["*://*.example.io/*"],
            "js": [
                "assets/js/inject.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
        "resources": ["assets/js/inject.js"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }], 
    "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": ["*://*.example.io/*"]
    },  
    "action": {
        "default_title": "Extension title",
        "default_icon": "assets/icons/icon-32.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "assets/icons/icon-16.png",
        "32": "assets/icons/icon-32.png",
        "48": "assets/icons/icon-48.png",
        "128": "assets/icons/icon-128.png"
    }

}
```

**my popup html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link defer rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/popup.css">
    <title>site</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <section class="site__root">
        <h1>site Auto<br></h1>
        <h2>Unpublished stories: <span class="unpublished-stories"></span></h2>
        <button id="publish_drafts" class="btn fourth">Publish drafted stories</button>
    </section>
    <script src="assets/js/content_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**inside my content_script included above:**

```
publishDraftedStoriesBtn = document.getElementById('publish_drafts');
clickEvent = (function() {
    if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement === true)
        return 'touchstart';
    else{
        return 'click';
    }
})();


function handlePublishDraftsResponse(resp){
    console.log(resp);
}

function handlePublishDraftsQuantityResponse(resp){
    document.querySelector('.unpublished-stories').textContent = response.ids;
}

function handleExtensionInit(resp){
    console.log(msg.result);
}


socket_content_tasks = {
    'initExtension': handleExtensionInit,
    'GetDraftedStoriesQuantity': handlePublishDraftsQuantityResponse,
    'PublishDrafts': handlePublishDraftsResponse,
};

var pathToInjectedCode = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "content-script"});

pathToInjectedCode.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if(msg.task in socket_content_tasks){
        socket_content_tasks[msg.task](msg.result);
    }
    
});

pathToInjectedCode.postMessage({task: "initExtension"});
pathToInjectedCode.postMessage({task: "GetDraftedStoriesQuantity"});


publishDraftedStoriesBtn.addEventListener(clickEvent, e => {
    console.log('Starting publishing!');
    pathToInjectedCode.postMessage({task: "PublishDrafts"});

})
```

**Inside my injected code i use this as reciver but it not working.**

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(pathToInjectedCode) {
    pathToInjectedCode.onMessage.addListener( async function(msg) {
        if (msg.task in socket_tasks){
            rslt = await socket_tasks[msg.task]();
            pathToInjectedCode.postMessage({result: rslt, task: msg.task});
        }
    });
});
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
I have no more detail I have no more detailI have no more detailI have no more detailI have no more detailI have no more detail

Comment: The popup runs only when shown. You should reverse the direction of messaging: let the popup send a message via chrome.tabs.sendMessage or chrome.tabs.connect to the active tab id.

Comment: @wOxxOm sir you are my saver) that's work, but can you help me a little more? when my page where extension work loading, create var inside window, i make fucntion that extract data from there, but when i press on extension it gives me error, but i i do it manualy it show me what need, but inside injected function not

Comment: I can't say what's wrong. Try setting breakpoints in devtools and debugging the code. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.